# Google place api android search shopping mall

Tags: google-places-api

I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yuwk05aKIZc .

I want to know how can i search current location and filter with type of shopping mall .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make a request using the **type** filter

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=shopping_mall&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can read about all the type filters [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

Comment: Can you give me some example code for android i very confuse how to use this line of code .